# Is there a better way of launching same app from GUI or Command line

Tags: cocoa, macos, command-line-interface, launching-application

I worked out a way of running my Cocoa (GUI) app. From either the normal double clicking it,
Or from the CLI.

I realised that when an app launches from a double click (GUI), it returns an argument count  (***argc***) of 2.

But when launched from the CLI it will have an ***argc*** of 1. So long as I do not put any arguments myself.

Which means I can use   *if.. else..* to determine how the app was launched.

This works fine for my app as I do not need to put arguments.

But I wondered if there was a better way of doing it.

Here is an example of the code in the  ***main.m***

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //This determins if the app is launched from the command line or app itself is opened.

    if (argc == 1) {
        //app was run from CLI
        // Create a  object
        MyClass *mMyClass;
        mMyClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        // Read the Buffer
        [mMyClass readBuffer];

        // Write out file on disk
        [mMyClass createFile];
        [mMyClass doMoreStuff]; 

        [mMyClass release];
        mMyClass = nil;

    return 0;
    } else {

    //app was doubled click, (Opened)

   return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);

   ;
   // */
   //  return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
   }
   [pool drain];
}
```

Many Thanks.
M

Comment: for me, this is an interesting question. 1 vote up.

Comment: Two comments.  1/ please format your code properly in future.  The SO formatter doesn't like tabs much. 2/ Technically, you only need to allocate and drain the autorelease pool on the command line branch.  `NSApplicationMain` creates its own pools.

Comment: JeremyP. 1/ Please don't assume I know how to do that or what the issue was with the formatting. I did not. Thank you for the heads up. 2/ Thank you for pointing out about the autorelease pool that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from checking the argc, you may want to consider checking the argv value itself.

**for apps running by double-clicking:**

```
1/4/11 9:43:30 AM   Untitled[605]   argc: 2
1/4/11 9:43:30 AM   Untitled[605]   argv0: /tmp/Untitled/build/Debug/Untitled.app/Contents/MacOS/Untitled
1/4/11 9:43:30 AM   Untitled[605]   argv1: -psn_0_131104
```

**for apps running in command line:**

```
1/4/11 9:43:44 AM   Untitled[608]   argc: 1
1/4/11 9:43:44 AM   Untitled[608]   argv0: ./Untitled
1/4/11 9:43:44 AM   Untitled[608]   argv1: (null)
```

Comment: Thanks Neilvert.When I look at the argv0 I get the same full path to the binary. I should point out that I am running the app from the CLI using the full path.

Comment: `argv[0]` by convention will be the name of the command as typed by you in the shell.

Comment: I wonder if checking for `-psn` in `argv[1]` is sufficient. Anyone knows that?

Comment: Thanks Bavarious. I think if I use argv[1]. Then I might as well use my own argument in the CLI. and look for that. Which I guess maybe a better way to go. Any other ideas welcome. Thanks

Comment: Update: I used a combination of checking argv1 for -psn and my own arguments for running the CLI. So I have accepted Neilvert Noval answer. But thanks also to Bavarious.